# Encrypted SWAP partition creation after ubuntu 15.04 installation, 15.04 installer bugs!

Tags: partitioning, encryption, 15.04, swap, luks

Today I decided to install clean copy of 15.04. Using the installer partitioning tool, I created an encrypted luks system volume, then created an unencrypted SWAP, clicked continue, then got an error message saying that I MUST create an encrypted SWAP for security reasons, however, there is no way I could create that SWAP from the installer! With a randomly generated key, I could find no way of doing this. I tried over 5 times to do it, but never succesful, I found online lots of articles about this problem but never found a working solution or an official one, and there is no other graphical tool that I could find that is able to deal with encrypted volumes. I tried using the command line without success. So and because I need to have my system up and running, I installed my system on a luks encrypted volume with no swap partition. Now I'm writing from my new system, I wan to create an encrypted SWAP with randomly generated key. How could I do that?, I need a complete solution please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to create an encrypted swap as follows:

1. create a partition for swap using fdisk or gparted (I used gparted), but do not format it as swap, instead, you could choose "cleared" as a format type in gparted.
2. Add the following to /etc/crypttab

> ```
> swap_crypt /path/to/swap/partition /dev/urandom swap
> ```

3. Then add the swap_crypt to /etc/fstab, here is how:

> ```
> /dev/mapper/swap_crypt none swap sw 0 0
> ```

4. Activate the swap:

> ```
> /etc/init.d/cryptdisks reload
> ```

```
swapon -a
```

5. Check that it's working:

> ```
> dmsetup info
> ```

```
cat /proc/swaps
```

Note1: After doing step 4 and, if the swap doesn't work, you simply need to restart, and then it's going to work.

Note2: Ubuntu Disks app didn't recognise the newly created swap, but it doesn't matter, you also won't see it on gparted, as gparted doesn't support LUKS/DM-CRYPT manipulation.

Note3: executing (dmsetup info) command, I got a result indicating that everything is okay but the last line of the result was the following and I didn't understand what does it mean:

> UUID: CRYPT-PLAIN-swap_crypt

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same boat! As of yesterday I tried to install using an encrypted luks and of course it required me to create an encrypted swap. Finally after about 5 attempts it wants the following: 1. encrypted volume mount at / , 2. Encrypted swap volume , 3. Unencrypted and separate /boot .

HOWEVER, even after doing this, I receive the error when proceeding to install: unable to mount / !!

Comment: Exactly, so now after installation, it's clear that creating an unencrypted swap is not an issue, but the question is how to create an encrypted one ? perhaps using dm crypt and luks but how, did you find any article about this ?